# using jQuery drag + drop to delete a row from an SQL table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

just a quick question.

Im using jQuerys Drag and Drop to print rows from an SQL table into my page like so

```
<?php
    include 'includes/connect.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM RSSFeeds";
    $results = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
?>
<li class="ui-state-default" data-value=<?php $row['ID']?>>
    <?php echo $row['name']?>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

This works fine, so my question is, how do I use the drop function to pass the value of the row to a delete function? which would then delete the entry from the database.

since simply putting: `$(ui.draggable).remove();` merely gets rid of the UI element from the page

I'm pretty new to this so if its a dumb question, just say. Any help would be greatly appreciated, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call an [AjaxFunction](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) in

```
.droppable({
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    // here
  }
});
```

that calls the PHP-Delete